# This program is automatically exiting after finishing any one action, why?

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, logic, exit

My program is exiting after giving one command every time and I am unable to find a logical reason why. I have checked all my loops and if-statements for exit codes but was not able to located any.
the program includes many classes and functions, but here is main:

```
int main()
{
    int local_location = 0;
    vector<string>Inventory = { "", "", "" };

    unordered_set<string> excl = { "in", "on", "the", "with" };

    string word;
    array<string, 2> command;
    size_t n = 0;


    command.at(1) = "";
    command.at(0) = "";



    while (n < command.size() && cin >> word) {
        auto search = excl.find(word);
        if (search == excl.end())
            command.at(n++) = word;
    }

    if (command.at(0) == "look") {
        look(command.at(1), local_location, Inventory);
    }
    else if (command.at(0) == "get") {
        look(command.at(1), local_location, Inventory);
    }

    else if (command.at(0) == "drop") {
        look(command.at(1), local_location, Inventory);
    }

    else if (command.at(0) == "bag") {
        bag(Inventory);
    }
    else if (command.at(0) == "go") {
        look(command.at(1), local_location, Inventory);
    }


}
```

Comment: think about it - you're looping until you get a command, then after you leave the loop you execute the command. There's nothing actually causing it to loop *after* you process the command

Comment: Yes. I tried to add while loop and also tries adding a do-while loop to main. both additions causes the program to infinitely loop the action caused by the first command I gave it.

Comment: you need to check that you reset the conditions that would otherwise cause it to skip over the command-reading while loop. e.g. once you've processed the command, set n to 0, otherwise `n < command.size()` will always evaluate to true, and it won't get the next command

Comment: Your use case is unclear. Even if you were to loop, all your if-checks are only on the first element of command[]. Am I missing something? Please explain what you wish your code performed, exactly?

Comment: Agreed with @Zac Faragher
If you want to get multiple commands, just use a while/ for loop. And create a command to exit the program. The loop should end(break) after the command is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over standard input and reset the condition on n after processing the command.

```
while(cin>>word)
{
   auto search = excl.find(word);
   if (search == excl.end())
       command.at(n++) = word;
   if (n== command.size())
   {
      // process the command
      // reset n=0
   }
}
```